# Getting layout.height after ListView size has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I have ListView that is using the onLayout prop to retrieve the initial layout properties. This ListView is also being filtered, where list items are being removed on added. How do I get the new height each time the size of the ListView is changed?

```
onLayoutAction = (event) => {
    var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout
    const {height} = layout
    this.setState({
        currentListHeight : height - 61
    })
}

  renderListView = () => {
    if (this.noRowData()) {
      return (
          <AlertMessage title='No Offerings Available' show={this.noRowData()} />
      )
    } else {
      // TODO: fix refreash control below
      return (
          <ListView
            ref='listView'
            onLayout={this.onLayoutAction}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            onScroll={this.onScrollAction}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
            renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
            enableEmptySections
            pageSize={15}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.props.isLoading}
                onRefresh={this.handleOnRefresh}
                tintColor='#000000'
                title='Loading...'
                titleColor='#000000'
                colors={['#000000', '#000000', '#000000']}
                progressBackgroundColor='#ffffff' />
              }
            />
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onLayout` function should be called on mount and on every layout change per the docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html

I did a quick test and added an `onLayout` function to a ListView in my app.  It was called every time that I added an item to the list.  I didn't test removing an item but I would assume it's the same.

You may also check out `onContentSizeChange`.  It fires every time the contents change in the ScrollView that ListView uses

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange